# sh steps hangs. How to have more logs

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**Context** : I have a jenkins controller running in docker, connected over ssh to a jenkins agent, also in docker, on the same network

I have this simple pipeline :

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'node:16.17.1-alpine' } }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It runs fine on the jenkins controller executor but I get a warning because it is better to execute jobs on agents. But when I execute the same job on a jenkins agent, the job hangs at the `sh` step and after 5 minutes, fails with this message :

> process apparently never started in /home/jenkins/workspace/Pipe@2@tmp/durable-8e3be35d
> (running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)

I have seen that this problem is common but proposed solutions did not work. I would like to add the variable suggested in the error message (`-Dorg.jenkinsci.[...].LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true`) but :

1. Should I use it on the controller or the agent ?
2. How do I do that in a jenkins that is embedded in Docker ? I don't launch the `java -jar agent.jar` myself, I just execute a container.

Here is the `Dockerfile` of the agent, it uses the official `jenkins/ssh-agent` + adds Docker client + some utils

```
FROM jenkins/ssh-agent
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl lsb-release openssh-client dnsutils htop vim nmap

RUN curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc \
  https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg
RUN echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) \
  signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc] \
  https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce-cli
```